# Where can i found MFC sample project for study?

Tags: mfc

When i found some questions, I always try to go to [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com) and [www.codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com) to find some sample projects or tutorial.
But sometime i found the resources from the codeproject and codeguru are not enought.

So can someone suggest me some better website which contains useful sample projects or tutorial about C++/MFC ... ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize you already mentioned CodeProject, but I must specifically point out the [ToDoList project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx). It is a great end-to-end example of a well-designed, correctly object-oriented MFC application. There are a lot of classes in that project that I have re-used in my own stuff. Not to mention, it's also a great app in its own right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, check out the MSDN How to videos for native code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb496952.aspx

Andrew

P.s. is what I am using. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides a bunch of MFC samples with Visual C++.  If they're not on your local machine, you can [download them from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482ck6x8%28VS.80%29.aspx).